# Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\store\search.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

so i am trying to implement search bar, in the blog i'm working on and when i search it gives me undefined variable post in `search.blade.php` and i have tried all i can . please help

heres my search.blade file

```
@extends('layouts.main')    
@section('content')     
    <div class="col-lg-8">     
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <h2>
                <a href="/store/{{ $post->id }}">{!! $post->title !!}</a>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">
                by <a href="index.php">{!! $post->author !!}</a>
            </p>
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on {!! $post->created_at !!}</p>
            <hr>
            <a href="/store/{{ $post->id }}">{!! Html::image('/img/posts/'. $post->image, $post->title, array('style'=>'width: 675px; height:225px;')) !!}</a>{
            <hr>
            <p>{!! $post->short_desc !!}</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/store/view/{{ $post->id }}">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

            <hr>
         @endforeach   
     </div>            
@endsection
```

And the controller function

```
public function getSearch(Request $request) { 
    $keyword = $request->input('keyword'); 
    $categories = Category::all(); 
    if( $keyword != ""){ 
        return view('store.search')->with('posts', Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get()) 
            ->with('keyword', $keyword) 
            ->with('categories', $categories); 
     } 
     else { 
         return redirect('/') ; 
     } 
}
```

Comment: post your controller code as well from where you are passing variable to the view

Comment: Can you please add your controller code here .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: i think you dont pass $posts from controller to your blade file.

Comment: without controller its very hard to say where is the error!

Comment: show the controller code

Comment: heres my store controller

Comment: public function getSearch(Request $request) {

        $keyword = $request->input('keyword');
        $categories = Category::all();

        if( $keyword != ""){

            return view('store.search')
                ->with('posts', Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get())
                ->with('keyword', $keyword)
                ->with('categories', $categories);
        } else {
       return redirect('/') ;
    } 

    }

Comment: have tested the way you code. don't get any error. try to test the variable with other values.

Comment: zahid i dont get you

Comment: i mean you just send the `posts` variable with a garbage value like `with('posts', 'csdnvnf')` and check if it throws error like `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: sorry please zahid write and example